# Update a table in one server when a new job is added to any other server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a bunch of servers and one server that keeps the inventory of all these servers.

I want to create a stored procedure which will automaticaly update a table called `Job Information` in my inventory server, whenever a new job is added to any of the other servers.

The `Job Information` table has the columns:

```
Server Name, Job Name, Date Created , Date Modified
```

Comment: If the table is only updated when a job is added, what purpose does the Date Modified column serve?

Comment: this is for the purposes of the jobs that are already running on those servers. Up untill now I have been putting this information manually but now my manager wants to fill these tables automatically..it would also be helpful if the stored procedure could update the table whenever a existing job is modified.... sorry for this... i am a new dba...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, each your servers can be reach your inventory server.

Add your jobs to your other servers with stored procedure.And in that procedure, write an extra insert statement for insert job to your inventory server.

```
INSERT INTO [SERVER].[dbo].[DATABASE].[TABLENAME] (Field1,Field2) VALUES ('Field1', 'Field2');
```

Comment: I don't know how feasible that is. Do you really want to create stored procedures for creating / editing jobs, steps, schedules etc.? You're reproducing code that already exists and you're preventing all the users from using the UI to create / modify jobs (which most people will be doing).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you for your critism.There is no information about project's scale.If it has thousands of users, you right.

Comment: If I am only one user and you took away my ability to create / modify jobs using the UI that was designed to do so, and forced me to learn the syntax for these stored procedures (which are unlikely, when written by an inexperienced DBA, to be fully functional and correct), then I'd still be upset. This has nothing to do with scale or number of users.

Comment: @codeGenius no, there are just 20 servers... the possibility of a link server and triggers on system tables is out... my manager pointed me in the direction of open query and i am not how can that help.... it would be sufficient if my stored procedure could querry each of the server once a day and update its table according to any changes in any of the server.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a linked server on each server that points to your inventory server. I'll assume you've already set that up and the linked server name is `InventoryServer`.

Then you can create a trigger on each server:

```
USE msdb;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UpdateNewJob
ON dbo.sysjobs
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT InventoryServer.DatabaseName.dbo.[Job Information]
    ([Server Name],[Job Name],[Date Created],[Date Modified])
    SELECT @@SERVERNAME, name, date_created, date_modified
      FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

To also update the `Date Modified` column you could add an additional trigger (or you could combine the logic into one):

```
USE msdb;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UpdateExistingJob
ON dbo.sysjobs
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE j
    SET [Date Modified] = i.date_modified
    FROM  InventoryServer.DatabaseName.dbo.[Job Information] AS j
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON i.name = j.name
    WHERE j.[Server Name] = @@SERVERNAME;
END
GO
```

Now you will also need to add on top of this error handling - for example what do you want to do when `InventoryServer` is unreachable? What do you do if a job name has changed? (Your central inventory table should probably hold the `job_id` in addition to the name.)

As an aside, please try to avoid naming tables and columns with spaces or other special characters - this only serves to force you to use `[square brackets]` in most places. Which do you find most/least readable? Be honest:

```
[Date Modified]

DateModified

Date_Modified
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise and I will surely follow that... For the code, my Manager wants no triggers on system tables or linked servers... it would be sufficient if there is a stored procedure on the inventory server which can query each server once a day and update its table according to any changes...maybe the use of open querry can help here....

Comment: How is the stored procedure on the inventory server going to query each of the individual servers without a linked server?

Comment: I am not sure....My manager pointed me in direction of open querry but i am new to it so reading up on it... I am really sorry for this confusion..... All your help is greatly appreciated....

Comment: @user1688976 so what is the point of maintaining this data in a table then? Why not just write a query that uses OpenQuery against all of the servers, and run it when you want the information? Then it's guaranteed to be up to date and you don't have to write some background process that maintains the information even when you don't need it...

Comment: I am sure that is a better way but i am in need to write this kind of stored procedure... what if we write this query and schedule it to run once every day and update the results in that table.... I know there is no point to it but this is a feasible solution... rite...

Comment: @user1688976 Sorry, I offered my solution before you added all of these additional rules and limitations. I have to do other work now, maybe someone else can help you write a query that performs the same sort of insert/update in the other direction.